# Integrating CUDA 4.0 into existing VS2008 project

Tags: visual-studio-2008, cuda

I wrote simple raytracer in C++ and I want to add CUDA to the project.
I edited my .vcproj manually and added Cudart Build Rule but I can't get it to work.
Nvcc is invoked cuda compiles ok, but it seems like host compiler doesn't recognize any of cuda types and kernel syntax.

My cuda version is 4.0 RC2, I can compile and run other CUDA projects.

Please help. Got deadline over my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that all your CUDA code is in `.cu` files such that they are compiled by NVCC, since NVCC understands the CUDA keywords.

Comment: Thank you for your response! That was pretty much the issue. I accidently included one of .cu files to my cpp code.